# Boost Spirit lexeme vs no_skip

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

As like the description on [Boost.Spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/lexeme.html), the only difference between lexeme and no_skip is the pre_skip.

But after some test, I'm still confusing about the exactly meaning for pre_skip.

So what kind of condition will make a difference, maybe a example can help me understand it much better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pre-skip ignores whitespace at the start of the expression.

Contrasting:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d5d234ad5154420)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
static std::string const input = " 42j";

int main() {
    auto run_test = [](auto p) {
        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        int i;
        return qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space, i)
            ? std::to_string(i)
            : "unparsed";
    };

    std::cout << "no_skip: " << run_test(qi::no_skip[ qi::int_ >> 'j' ]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "lexeme: "  << run_test(qi::lexeme[ qi::int_ >> 'j' ]) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
no_skip: unparsed
lexeme: 42
```

As you can see `lexeme` will silently eat the leading white space. *That's the pre-skip.*

Comment: Excellent explanation! Seems like I test the lexeme and no_skip in a wrong way. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Just realized I could have made the tester more succinct: [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e366c5b5b1275608). Doesn't really change anything of course :)

Comment: Oh, my standard backgrounder about skippers is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965 - granted it didn't exactly provide an example like this

Comment: I had viewed the question when I searched about this topic, but no succinct example there. Since you provide it, I can realize the difference between these. Actually I had guessed the answer before, but maybe my test code is a little bit complicate so that some another factors affect the test result. I'm going to check out that. Thanks again for your positive response. :)

Comment: @sehe I see that the difference between lexeme and no_skip is in pre_skip (e.g. pre-space is eat or not). They are the same for in_skip (in-space is not eat). And if you want to disable post_skip? I see that in all situations post_skip is performed (eat post-space in input "42j "). See a quick&dirty modification of your example: https://godbolt.org/z/PfxP7bh15

Comment: @ClaudiuCruceanu I don't think I understand what you're trying to say ("They are the same"? "[...] for in_skip" (?) and "in-space is not eat"? If you're saying that to colonize Mars we will need to bring food, then I agree :) Here's some more side-by-side info on skippers in Qi: ichess.org/racer

Comment: @sehe I only quote from the master :) :"As you can see lexeme will silently eat the leading white space. That's the pre-skip." . And I generalized using expressions like in-skip, post-skip, in-space and post-space. The important issue is that for pre-skip and in-skip we have control but I saw that we cannot disable post-skip. P.S. probably "ichess.org/racer" is not complete/typo.

Comment: @sehe Actualy forget about Marte :)) you can ignore the preamble ;) and pull up a magic :) trick to answer my (more or less ) implicit question: How is possible to disable space skipping after the rule?

Comment: Oops that's a clipboard failure yes, should have been https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073965/85371. I still don't really know what `in-skip` is (other than... just a skipper maybe). Pre/post-skip, yes those make sense. in-space/post-space are very confusing to me. I don't see it in my posts or your code. Did you post a question about disabling post-skipping?

Comment: @ClaudiuCruceanu Here's what I think will help you. If you don't want skipping, do not use a skipper: https://godbolt.org/z/aMzcodofr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252829/discussion-between-claudiu-cruceanu-and-sehe).

Answer (score 1):

Tecnically speaking skipping happens before calling rules parser. So all directives within a `lexeme` parsing statement will act as an atom, skipper will be invoked before the begining of the lexeme clause as usual but not between rules within the clause.

The `no_skip` directive "wont invoke" any skipper at all as stated by the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_skip.html). It will act as `lexeme` if there is no white space to skip, but that's a subtle difference. It's more appropriate when parsing binary files.