# Boost Spirit X3: skip parser that would do nothing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm getting myself familiarized with boost spirit v3. The question I want to ask is how to state the fact that you don't want to use skip parser in any way.

Consider a simple example of parsing comma-separated sequence of integers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    const std::string input{"2,4,5"};

    const auto parser = int_ % ',';
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    auto start = input.cbegin();
    auto r = phrase_parse(start, input.end(), parser, space, numbers);

    if(r && start == input.cend())
    {
        // success
        for(const auto &item: numbers)
            std::cout << item << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cerr << "Input was not parsed successfully" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This works totally fine. However, I would like to forbid having spaces in between (i.e. `"2, 4,5"` should not be parsed well).

I tried using `eps` as a skip parser in `phrase_parse`, but as you can guess, the program ended up in the infinite loop because `eps` matches to an empty string.

Solution I found is to use `no_skip` directive (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_skip.html). So the parser now becomes:

```cpp
const auto parser = no_skip[int_ % ','];
```

This works fine, but I don't find it to be an elegant solution (especially providing `"space"` parser in `phrase_parse` when I want no whitespace skips). Are there no skip parsers that would simply do nothing? Am I missing something?

Thanks for Your time. Looking forward to any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `no_skip[]` or `lexeme[]`. They're almost identical, except for pre-skip ([Boost Spirit lexeme vs no_skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234428/boost-spirit-lexeme-vs-no-skip/63236980#63236980)).

> Are there no skip parsers that would simply do nothing? Am I missing something?

A wild guess, but you might be missing the `parse` API that doesn't accept a skipper in the first place

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef8fdc288b264445)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {
    std::string const input{ "2,4,5" };
    auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);

    const auto parser = x3::int_ % ',';
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    auto r = parse(f, l, parser, numbers);

    if (r) {
        // success
        for (const auto& item : numbers)
            std::cout << item << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Input was not parsed successfully" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining input " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
2
4
5
```

Comment: PS. For the skipper that matches literally nothing, [use `x3::eps(false)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b15f0493d3a342b). It just crossed my mind that after all the more relevant info you might still have been curious.

Comment: Thanks, `eps(false)` did the trick. As for the `phrase_parse` overload without skip parser, the example above works well but it doesn't for some more elaborate parsers. Don't know why though

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965. Most things  apply mutatis mutandis to Spirit X3 (except that skippers are now strictly part of the context)